# Change 2 colors of a texture among the 4 colors of a texture in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, shaders

I have a texture issue with my character. Indeed my character does not have the right colors except black and white. I tried changing the colors of the textures with Cycles but not sure how to do it. When I use Cycles and render the character has the correct skin color however this color affects the area around his eyes as well as his wings and ears which I don't want that color.

The texture colors of the 3d model before and after rendering:
[image: screenhot 1]

[image: screenhot 2]

Comment: Hi there, could you upload the .blend file using blendswap so other members can take a look at the problem? There isn't much info to work with here.

Comment: I have worked on the model but it is not the right color yet. I put on the left and on the right 2 cubes which must correspond to one of the colors of the model. The ears and wing membranes should be colored pink while the fur should be colored purple. Only the black and white colors seem to be correct (even if there is purple in the character's eye). Otherwise I'll show you how I proceeded in terms of nodes.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hvm3zT9j9cz2zWc6iXOjVWTM2MBTOLAp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gBxO2JU8W8SkcTbVsXPH9g9qTlY7v1IE/view?usp=sharing